# How to get QTextEdit's html tags without getting all of the html?

Tags: html, c++, qt

I've got a QTextEdit which I'm storing some text in from a variable called m_text. The text is stored in there like:

`&lt;ui>&lt;center>Info Plot&lt;/center>&lt;ui> &lt;br> &lt;table> &lt;tr> &lt;td> Name: &lt;/td> &lt;td> 50A40 &lt;/td> &lt;/tr>` etc...

This is what's stored in m_text anyway, it's essentially the text that I need plus some html to make it display the way I want, using a table, some underline etc.

I set the text on the QTextEdit by using setText(m_text), storing exactly what's in the variable into the edit text. My question is, how can I get that exact text back out, maybe with a few user additions (say they want to change it a bit)? toPlainText() returns everything except the html tags and toHtml() returns a massive string with loads of stuff I don't need or want (and I would like to not have to search through if possible).

I've written my entire code using these basic structure tags (like table) as a template for getting certain information out and changing other bits of information, therefore I'd like to keep the way I've done it if I can.

Is there anyway I can get all the data + the tags I have put in back out, the same way it was set from `m_text`?

Edit:

```
#include <QDialog>


class plotInfoDialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    plotInfoDialog();
    void setQTextEdit();
    void getFreeTextEditText();

 public slots:
    void editChange();

 private:
    QString m_text;

 };

 plotInfoDialog::plotInfoDialog() {

    m_ui = new Ui::plotInfoDialog();
    m_ui->setupUi(this);
    this->show();
    m_text = "<u> <center>Plot Info</center> </u> <br><table><tr><td>Name: </td><td> #BASENAME#</td></tr><tr><td>Date: </td><td>#DATE# </td></tr><tr><td>Time: </td><td>#TIME# </td></tr><tr><td>Radar: </td><td>#RADAR#</td></tr><tr><td>Polarization: </td><td> #P#</td></tr><tr><td>Range: </td><td>#RANGE# </td></tr><tr><td>Elevation: </td><td> #ELEV# </td></tr></table>";
    setQTextEdit();
    connect(m_ui->FreeTextEdit->document(), SIGNAL(contentsChange(int,int,int)), this, SLOT(editChange(int,int,int)));

}

void plotInfoDialog::setQTextEdit() {

    m_ui->FreeTextEdit->setText(m_text);
}

void plotInfoDialog::editChange(int pos, int del, int add)
{
    //update m_text with changes in FreeTextEdit here
}

void plotInfoDialog::getFreeTextEditText() {
    m_text = //get text from FreeTextEdit here
}
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: The code is quite long and I'm not sure what you'd need to see. This is where the QTextEdit is being set: m_ui->FreeTextEdit->setText(m_text); m_text is changed constantly throughout the code but it's originally set to this: "<u> <center>Plot Info</center> </u> <br><table><tr><td>Name: </td><td> #BASENAME#</td></tr><tr><td>Date: </td><td>#DATE# </td></tr><tr><td>Time: </td><td>#TIME# </td></tr><tr><td>Radar: </td><td>#RADAR#</td></tr><tr><td>Polarization: </td><td> #P#</td></tr><tr><td>Range: </td><td>#RANGE# </td></tr><tr><td>Elevation: </td><td> #ELEV# </td></tr></table>"

Comment: I just need to be able to get something like that back out, including all those tags but not including things that I don't need like font size etc.

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When you have it, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47019184/edit) and add it.

Comment: I know it's not that helpful but there's a lot of code and it's for the company I work for so I shouldn't really be sharing large portions of it. Any help will be appreciated however as I really am not sure how to go about fixing this.

Comment: I did not say that you share the code of your company, but take the time and create a mvce. Those excuses are silly.

Comment: Ok there's a basic version of it, I just need to get the text as it appears when it's being set back out from FreeTextEdit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually when you `setText()` and when you ask your text with `toPlainText()`, the returned string maintains your HTML tags.

But in your case some where the string in `QTextEdit` is converted as HTML. So the returned string from `toPlainText()` is missing all your HTML tags. Look for all the references of `QTextEdit` and see anywhere HTML conversion is happening.

**The alternate is:**

Use `QPlainTextEdit`, if you do not want HTML at all, I mean your tags will be well preserved.

Try as said below.

to set the text

```
QPlainTextEdit *textEdit = new QPlainTextEdit();
QString m_text = "<ui><center>Info Plot</center><ui> <br> <table> <tr> <td> Name: </td> <td> 50A40 </td> </tr>";
textEdit->document()->setPlainText(m_text);
```

To get the text back

```
m_text = textEdit->toPlainText();
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. I would have preferred it if I could have got the html tags back while also actually using the html but since it doesn't look like there's a way to do that I think I'll just add two displays, one for editing (plainTextEdit) and one for viewing the finished text, using the html (textEdit).